# Two similar javascript functions, one works, the other doesnt, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a Javascript beginner, I am trying to get some simple code working. I added one snippet as a check to make sure Javascript is working in the page, which it does. It just changes a bit of text from blue to red.

The second piece of code is supposed to hide a `<div>`, or show it depending on the selected value. It does not work can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks for any advice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>getElementById example</title>
  <script>
  function changeColor(newColor) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
    elem.style.color = newColor;
  }
  </script>

  <script>
       // EXPAND
    function Hide(elementid){
        document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
    }

    function Show(elementid){
        document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    }
  </script>

</head>
    <body>
        <p id="para1">Some text here</p>
        <button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
        <button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>

        <div id="one">ONE</div>
        <div id="two">TWO</div>

        <select>
            <Option value="javascript:Show('one');javascript:Hide('two')">one</option> 
            <Option value="javascript:Hide('one');javascript:Show('two')">two</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using the "value" attribute to manage events?

Comment: A "point in the right direction" would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this sort of thing.

Comment: You can't put javascript into the `value` of an `option`.  You need the `onchange` event of the `select`.  You might consider reading up on html forms and how they work, then reading up on javascript events.

Comment: Its not an anwer to your question, but you should look at this code. http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/  its a better way to hide/show a div.

Comment: please stop recommending using a framework for adding one event to one combobox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `value` attribute does not run JavaScript.

You need to bind a `change` event to the select element, and then look at the selected value to determine which one to show or hide.

[For example](http://jsbin.com/alimel/1/edit):

```
<div id="one">ONE</div>
<div id="two">TWO</div>
<div id="three">THREE</div>

<select>
    <option>one
    <option>two
    <option>three
</select>

<script>
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
  }
  function hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
  function whichDiv(event) {
    var select = event.target;
    var options = select.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      var option = options[i];
      if (option.selected) {
        show(option.value);
      } else {
        hide(option.value);
      }
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', whichDiv);
</script>
```

Comment: Cant believe how fast you put this together. Thanks very much! Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  `block` : `document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'block';`

Comment: No. Setting the display value to `''` will remove any inline value assigned there and allow the previous cascaded value to apply instead. Since there is no author stylesheet, that value will be from the browser stylesheet which defaults to `block` for div elements.